# Multiple GPU laptop not using NVIDIA card

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, gpu

I am using a HP Spectre x360 15 Inch with 2 grapihcs cards:

- Intel UHD Graphics 630
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design

Sadly the NVIDIA card only wakes up when disabling the Intel GPU, but this makes it impossible to control the laptop's brightness.

For example the application AutoCAD which asks quite a lot of GPU power. In the NVIDIA control panel AutoCAD is set to High-performance, as well as in Windows. The laptop is on High performance in battery mode and is charging.

[image: Screenshot of NVIDIA Control Panel settings]

[image: Screenshot of Windows graphics settings]

Is there a solution for this to work? For example when charging using the NVIDIA card when plugged out use Intel card for power saving, (or even just using NVIDIA card as standard on high performance without the need to disable the Intel one).

I have confirmed that the Intel UHD takes over by looking into the Task Manager; the NVIDEA stays at 0%:

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: Your screenshots indicated you have configured your system and application in question to use your Nvidia GPU, how did you determine, that isn't happening.  Be sure you edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @WouterDumon did you ever figure this out, having the exact same issue.

Comment: hi @Wjdavis5 getting rid of the docking station and updating to the latest bios update fixed it for me +-. it still isn't what i expect it to be ( uses both now and not pure gpu) but graphic wise there are no delays anymore so i'll take that for now :).